# Batch file to run programs as admin - error 740

Tags: windows-7, command-line, batch-file

I am working on a small batch script that elevates basic windows programs to run as administrator.

All of the functions work fine but I have ran into a problem when trying to run "regedit.exe".

When option 3 is selected in the script and it should run regedit as admin I get error:

> 740: The requested operation requires elevation.

Here is the script:

```
echo off
cls
echo.
echo Start as admin:
echo /----------------\
echo # 1. CMD         #
echo # 2. Task Manager#
echo # 3. Regedit     #
echo # 0. Exit        #
echo \----------------/
echo.

set /p run=

if %run%==1 (
set run="cmd"
)

if %run%==2 (
set run="taskmgr"
)

if %run%==3 (
set run="regedit"
)

if %run%==0 (
exit
)

runas /savecred /user:admin %run%
```

Is there a workaround for this?

*I would like make this working without installing third party programs, modifying the registry or disabling UAC.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pull it off by launching a new CMD prompt with RunAs, which you tell to launch your command.

To do this in your batch, change the last line to:

`runas /savecred /user:admin "cmd /c %run%"`

Comment: PS: Check out `choice /?`. :)

Comment: I have one more question. Since I have implemented your method, my error handling doesn't work. What I mean by that is, if the command is not recognized, `errorlevel` is no longer set to `1` since it is run in another window. Is there a way to somehow make it 1 again if there is a typo in the input? (what I mean by that is: no choice numbers or valid CMD command is given)

Answer (score 2):

```
Add this to the top of your Batch file and at the end just put %run% instead of (runas /savecred /user:admin %run%)


@echo off

:: BatchGotAdmin
:-------------------------------------
REM  --> Check for permissions
>nul 2>&1 "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\cacls.exe" "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\config\system"

REM --> If error flag set, we do not have admin.
if '%errorlevel%' NEQ '0' (
    echo Requesting administrative privileges...
    goto UACPrompt
) else ( goto gotAdmin )

:UACPrompt
    echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    set params = %*:"=""
    echo UAC.ShellExecute "cmd.exe", "/c %~s0 %params%", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"

    "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    exit /B

:gotAdmin
    pushd "%CD%"
    CD /D "%~dp0"
:--------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13756216/running-a-set-up-file-in-a-batch-as-an-admin/13869544#13869544) can help, or maybe starting the entire batch as admin may help, done by creating another batch script containing:

```
runas /user:admin C:\Path_to_your_batch_file\name.bat
```

Comment: The reason I created this, is because the admin password is so long and I don't want to type it every time, so because of '/savecred' I don't have to. Tried to create another bat and run it from this one, it prompts me for the password and after I type it, I get `RUNAS ERROR: Unable to run - ...\regedit.bat` `-2147467259: Unspecified error`

Answer (score 0):

1. Right-Click C:\Windows\regedit.exe and choose Properties
2. In the Compatibility-Tab choose "Run this program as an administrator"

Comment: This is what I wanted to avoid. We have 16 digit admin password and typing it every time even on my own PC is a bit annoying. Using the `/savecred` will only have to type it once and that's it.